# Как через JS создать некликабельный элемент поверх другого элемента?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Есть необходимость сделать элемент некликабельным (не на своём сайте), т.е. не трогая первоначальный элемент; Хочу сделать это через создание невидимого некликабельного элемента поверх необходимого

Comment: Так а в чем сложности? Создайте элемент, укажите его позицию, определите стиль элемента, разместите на странице.

Comment: Я без преувеличений новичок в JS

Comment: Просто дело в том, что за вас решать вашу задачу никто не будет, пока не увидят ваш код, ваши попытки решить задачу самостоятельно. Поэтому вот вам ссылка на полезный материал: http://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document, а как появятся конкретные вопросы - задавайте, будем рады помочь.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать